# Full trace in eclipse debugging session

Tags: eclipse, debugging, trace

I have a question about eclipse debugging. I would like to have, in an output file, all the calls of methods for a debugging session. I would like to track the methods called, all of theme, just like the in debug view but not only for a break point but for all the debug session.

Using breakpoints does not allow to know which methods were called before. Knowing that could help placing break points efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Java debugger has no tracing capabilities. You need to look at other tools like the Yourkit profiler (which I used often for traces and benchmarking) or JProfiler.

Comment: Thanks Bananeweizen for your answer